# How to run overleaf locally

Tags: overleaf, latexmk, build-system

So far I have been working exclusively online via Overleaf. But now I would like to switch to working offline as well. I would like my compilation process to mimic the one by Overleaf exactly. I tried to read [how does Overleaf compile my project](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F). I saw that it uses latexmk so I went ahead and installed it. (I also have texlive-latex-extra on my machine,running Ubuntu 18.04, if that makes any difference). Now, according to the article I linked I should add that code to latexmkrc file. But I have no such file so I am stuck. If anyone could provide any help it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E.! Paste the content of this code to a file and name it .latexmkrc. You should also check if your texlive-latex-extra comes from the same year as the one installed on overleaf.

Comment: @sztruks My texlive-latex-extra is practically new. I just installed it a couple of days ago. So I assume there's no problem there. I did as you said. Then run latexmk main.tex and got an error which I don't get with overleaf.

Comment: @sztruks The error was actually unrelated so I think you pretty much solved my problem. If you post it as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: overleaf runs texlive2019 (with a specific set of updates) so any texkive is almost identical but you may have slightly different package versions.(overleaf will be updating to 2020 soon for new projects)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So unless I am working with a complete new package I will be good either way, is that what you are saying?

Comment: yes and even then you can upload it to your overleaf project if needed.

Comment: That's really nice. Thanks for pointing it out. I think it will come very handy when finishing a project to quickly view overleaf's pdf screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any latexmkrc file, open a new file in your $HOME directory, and name it `.latexmkrc` (if it is in your `document` directory, may be named either `latexmkrc` or `.latexmkrc`, as stated by Johh Collins in comments) and paste settings given in this article there.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I recommend to edit it to add the dot in front of the filename to be 100% correct.

Comment: latexmk reads both `latexmkrc` and `.latexmkrc`, both are correct.

Comment: @AlexWatson Are you 100% about this? Because I tried with a non dotted file and it didn't work.

Comment: Actually in the **home** directory, the filename must have the dot in front of it: `.latexmkrc`.  In contrast, in the **document** directory that it can be `latexmkrc` or `.latemkrc`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnCollins and sorry about the confusion. Yes, I always put my rc file in the document directory and omit the dot.